# elemnt:hover - text and background

Tags: css

I need text to appear on image once you hover it, and also I need it to affect the opacity.

Have a look at this pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNBgbQ

```
 <div class="flex-menu">
 <div class="menu-container">
 <img class="menu-image" src="http://www.libbyroach.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Adams-Sandwich.jpg" alt="Sandwitch">
 <div class="menu-description">

 <h4>Sandwitch</h4>
 <p>Powder marshmallow marshmallow brownie carrot cake candy bonbon. Sweet sugar plum gummies caramels tart carrot cake tiramisu cheesecake. Cheesecake biscuit jelly beans. Jelly-o icing chocolate macaroon. </p>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

The result I am looking for:

Hover over, the image changes its opacity and text appears on the middle of it - any text, not necessary the current heading and paragraph.

Comment: Thanks guys, both methods work as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positioning the text div with `'position:abolsute` to cover the image is the start.

The `.menu-container` div gets `position:relative` to provide a positioning context.

Then switch the `:hover` trigger to the wrapper to trigger both at once.

```css
.flex-menu,
.menu-container,
.menu-image {
  width: 500px;
}
.menu-container {
  position: relative;
}
.menu-description {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.flex-menu {
  background-color: #fd5c63;
}
.menu-image {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  display: block;
}
.flex-menu:hover .menu-image {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.flex-menu:hover .menu-description {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-menu">
  <div class="menu-container">
    <img class="menu-image" src="http://www.libbyroach.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Adams-Sandwich.jpg" alt="Sandwitch">
    <div class="menu-description">

      <h4>Sandwitch</h4>
      <p>Powder marshmallow marshmallow brownie carrot cake candy bonbon. Sweet sugar plum gummies caramels tart carrot cake tiramisu cheesecake. Cheesecake biscuit jelly beans. Jelly-o icing chocolate macaroon.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Position text over image with `position: absolute;`

I have moved `:hover` from `.menu-image` to `.menu-container`, some transitions changes to look better:

```css
.flex-menu,
.menu-container,
.menu-image {
  width: 500px;
}
.flex-menu {
  background-color: #fd5c63;
}
.menu-image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
}
.menu-container:hover .menu-image {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.menu-container {
  position: relative;
}
.menu-description {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 8;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.menu-container:hover .menu-description {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-menu">
  <div class="menu-container">
    <img class="menu-image" src="http://www.libbyroach.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Adams-Sandwich.jpg" alt="Sandwitch">
    <div class="menu-description">

      <h4>Sandwitch</h4>
      <p>Powder marshmallow marshmallow brownie carrot cake candy bonbon. Sweet sugar plum gummies caramels tart carrot cake tiramisu cheesecake. Cheesecake biscuit jelly beans. Jelly-o icing chocolate macaroon.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```